# How to configure sites on different instances of apache2

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost, multiple-instances, sites

I am running two different instances of `apache2` on my system, which are (obviously) running on different ports- 12345 and 12346.

I want to configure `localhost` to access different locations in both cases.

Here is my site which I have enabled: (`try.conf`)

```
# Virtual Host Entries
<VirtualHost *:12346>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/server2"
    ServerName localhost
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    <Directory "/var/www/server2">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# Virtual Host Entries
<VirtualHost *:12345>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/server1"
    ServerName localhost
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    <Directory "/var/www/server1">
        Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

When I open `localhost:12345`, I'm getting the desired web-page which is not the case with `localhost:12346`, in which case, instead of index in `server2` directory, I'm getting my `www`-directory shown.

This site, `try.conf` is in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`.

It does not matter whether or not I put it in `/etc/apache2-server1/sites-available` (second instance of apache) or not as `a2ensite` command to enable any configuration as such takes former path by default.

So, is there any way I can separately define my `.conf` files for both instances. If not, what is the problem here with my `try.conf`

Comment: did you reload apache after conf file changed. `sudo service apache2 reload`

Comment: You're running different apache instances or merely listening on more than one port?

Comment: Different apache instances... And yes... I'm reloading both apache instances :)

Comment: How are you starting each of the apache servers?

Comment: `service apache2 start` and `service apache2-server1 start`, or `reload/restart`